# Inserting cookie value into hidden fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, textfield, forms

I'm having trouble getting two cookie values and adding them to a form field on my website. Below is the script I've added, which also populates the values in JavsScript Console; however I can't get the cookie values into the form fields.

**Form fields:**

```
<input type="text" id="usource" name="usource" value="">
<input type="text" id="referrer" name="referrer" value="">
```

**I've tried this JS to populate the "usource" and "referrer" field, but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?**

```
document.getElementById("usource").value = utmCookie.utm_source;
document.getElementById("referrer").value = utmCookie.referrer;
```

This is the script I'm using which saves UTM parameters in cookies whenever there are any UTM parameters in the URL. It also saves the initial referrer information in a cookie which is ever (365 days) overwritten.

```html
var utmCookie = {
 
 
  cookieNamePrefix: "",
 
  utmParams: [
  "utm_source",
  "utm_medium",
  "utm_campaign",
  "utm_term",
  "utm_content"
  ],
 
  cookieExpiryDays: 365,
 
  // From http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
  createCookie: function (name, value, days) {
  if (days) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  } else
  var expires = "";
  document.cookie = this.cookieNamePrefix + name + "=" + value + expires + "; domain=.mywebsite.com; path=/";
  },
 
  readCookie: function (name) {
  var nameEQ = this.cookieNamePrefix + name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
  var c = ca[i];
  while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
  c = c.substring(1, c.length);
  if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0)
  return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
  }
  return null;
  },
 
  eraseCookie: function (name) {
  this.createCookie(name, "", -1);
  },
 
  getParameterByName: function (name) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  console.log(name);
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if (results == null) {
  return "";
  } else {
  return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }
  },
 
  utmPresentInUrl: function () {
  var present = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.utmParams.length; i++) {
  var param = this.utmParams[i];
  var value = this.getParameterByName(param);
  console.log(param + ' = ' + value);
  if (value != "" && value != undefined) {
  present = true;
  }
  }
  return present;
  },
 
  writeUtmCookieFromParams: function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.utmParams.length; i++) {
  var param = this.utmParams[i];
  var value = this.getParameterByName(param);
  this.writeCookieOnce(param, value)
  }
  },
 
  writeCookieOnce: function (name, value) {
  var existingValue = this.readCookie(name);
  if (!existingValue) {
  this.createCookie(name, value, this.cookieExpiryDays);
  }
  },
 
  writeReferrerOnce: function () {
  value = document.referrer;
  if (value === "" || value === undefined) {
  this.writeCookieOnce("referrer", "direct");
  } else {
  this.writeCookieOnce("referrer", value);
  }
  },
 
  referrer: function () {
  return this.readCookie("referrer");
  }
};
 
utmCookie.writeReferrerOnce();
 
if (utmCookie.utmPresentInUrl()) {
  utmCookie.writeUtmCookieFromParams();
}
```